# How to handle "The GenerateResourceDesigner task failed unexpectedly" error in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

This is my first application in xamarin forms and I have got error as given below. How to handle it?

[image]

Comment: When I get this error, it's because one of my .resx files wasn't built. Solution (for me) is to right click .resx file, choose run custom tool. After, I clean, rebuild, and problem solved.

Comment: Thanks... But This is not worked for me...

Comment: Did you find a fix for this @DipakAkhade?

Comment: @binncheol I am using Xamarin Studio instead of VS because of such number of errors. I did't found any such error in XS.

Answer (score 0):

I found that one of my shared files was running some iOS specific code. I put that code into an #if **IOS** block and it ran just fine.